# "Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined"

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to make Emberjs work with the fortunejs backend. So far I made a very simple page in Ember that should show all the 'customer' entities, which works fine with the LSadapter.

When my app loads the overview page, its does a GET request to `http://localhost:1337/customers` and fortune responds with:

```
{
"customers": [
{
  "id": "YIR17juOFkaWBFhl",
  "name": "PIm",
  "phone": 132,
  "fax": 123,
  "chamberOfCommerceNumber": 123,
  "website": "123.nl"
},
{
  "id": "gUGIoHvwI8mwVTgE",
  "name": "Marco",
  "phone": 123,
  "fax": 123,
  "chamberOfCommerceNumber": 123,
  "website": "it.nl"
}]}
```

However, ember does not seem to like it and gives me:

> "Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not
>   undefined"

I thought that this is the right json format ember expects from a get request to get all customers, what is going wrong?

FYI, I made a create page that works fine with fortunejs. For that I had to modify the RESTSerializer like so:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
serialize: (record, options) ->
    [this._super record, options] #Turn into array

serializeIntoHash: (hash, type, record, options) ->
    console.log type.typeKey
    type.typeKey = Ember.Inflector.inflector.pluralize type.typeKey #pluralize root key
    console.log type.typeKey
    console.log record
    result = this._super hash, type, record, options

});
```

But this should have nothing to do with the incoming JSON form the api.

Any ideas what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, and I'm not sure Stack Overflow's policy on that but I was trolling through unanswered questions to see if I knew any off the top of my head...

I think the problem here is that findAll (which doesn't exist in the current version of Ember Data) is a method that only does a store lookup. The equivalent of `store.all` in the current version (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_all).

You would want `store.find`, which makes a backend server request for the data (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_find).

Hope this helps anyone who stumbles across this problem...